# Difference between when the callback runs in JavaScript vs C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

JavaScript callback runs only when the call stack is empty. That happens either when the program execution finishes or when the main program calls `await`.

The callback in case of Task library in C#:

1. Assuming single thread program, behaves the same as JS (assuming `await` is used and not `.Wait` which would cause deadlock).
2. However in case of using `Task.Run`, or configure await false, the callback will run immediately when the response is ready. I am assuming each thread has its own call stack.

Is this correct distinction between when the callback runs in case of JS and C#?

Comment: "JavaScript callback runs only when the call stack is empty." What do you mean by this? Are you talking about Promises?

Comment: I think the only important thing to consider, in both Javascript and C# (and probably others) is that the callback is run "sometime in the future after completion". "When", exactly, is indeterminate and it shouldn't matter really. In both cases it'll be run whenever the thread it's scheduled on has a spare time, to put in simple words.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct distinction between when the callback runs in case of JS and C#?

Not really.

In JavaScript, the continuation always runs on the main thread *when it is not doing anything else*. Even if you `await` a `Promise` that's already complete, it's as though you called `setTimeout` without a delay. The code *always* yields whenever there's an `await`. [IMO](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), the JavaScript approach is cleaner and easier to understand than C#. However, the .NET team adopted a different approach for C#, I assume for performance reasons.

In C#, the first thing to note is that [`await` may continue executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). If the awaitable is already complete, then there's no yielding that takes place and no continuation exists *at all* - the code just continues executing in the same method. If the awaitable is not already complete, then a continuation is attached to the awaitable along with the current context (`SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current`).

When the awaitable completes, then it executes all its continuations. [If it's possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/), then the continuation is executed on the current thread (the one that completed the awaitable). If this kind of "inline continuation" isn't possible, then the continuation is *queued* to the context (`SynchronizationContext` / `TaskScheduler`). What happens then is entirely dependent on the context. E.g., UI contexts will queue continuations to the UI message processing loop, which is pretty much the same as `setTimeout` in JavaScript. As another example, the thread pool context will queue continuations to the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference is: single-thread vs multi-thread

I think, in your case, callback is called from different thread.
Learn more about `TaskScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext` to achieve your endeavour.